# Hacer un seleccionador de archivos en java

Tags: java, archivo

quiero crear un botón que cuando al precionarlo abra el explorador de archivos y desde hay se pueda seleccionar un archivo. E buscado en internet y no e encontrado nada.

Ese es el código de mi archivo main:

```
public class Main{
      public static void Main(String[] arg){
             JFrame frame = new JFrame("frame de prueba");
             Dimension screen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
             frame.setSize((int)screen.getWidth(),(int)screen.getHeight());
             frame.setJMenuBar(new jmenu());
        
             frame.setVisible(true);
      }
}



class jmenu extends JMenuBar implementa ActionListener{
     public jmenu{
           JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
           JMenuItem open = new JMenuItem("Open");
           open.addActionListener(this);
            this.add(file);
            file.add(open);
     }
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            // Aquí el codigo
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sería con un `JFileChooser`

```
JFileChooser j = new JFileChooser("c:");
```

Te dejo acá la documentación de la clase

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html